# Can't find launch activity

Tags: android

I removed these 2 lines from my android manifest file. Then I found them in internet and paste it to manifest file. And now my app can't find them. When I run my app says that there is no launcher activity and that may be I want to launch default activity.What can I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.amadey.myapplication3" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>

                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                </intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen">
            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post the full manifest, please?

Comment: @cricket_007   I've edited it, take a look

Comment: Why do you have an intent-filter tag inside an intent-filter tag?

Comment: @adelphus Hey man,thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a doubly-nested intent-filter element in your manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</intent-filter>
```

It needs to look like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because an intent filter was surrounded with another intent filter, just like this:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```